# BiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_WEAK) returns BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED on release build on Samsung and OnePlus devices

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

We are dealing with an issue in biometric where Biometric is working fine on all devices with apk build. We have uploaded same build (app bundle) on play store for closed testing and noticed that Biometric is not working on some device manufactures. We are getting BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED even if fingerprint is already there on device.

Working on:
Google Pixel 3a - Android 12

Motorola Edge 20 - Android 12

Redmi Note 9 Pro - Android 11

Not Working on:

Samsung M32 - Android 11

Samsung Galaxy S21 - Android 12

**Note**: Biometric works if I install app using apk on the same device on which it is not working

**OBSERVED RESULTS:** canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_WEAK) returns BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED

**EXPECTED RESULTS:** canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_WEAK) should return BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS

Biometric library versions tried

Version 1.0.1

mBiometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)
mBiometricManager.canAuthenticate()

Version 1.1.0 (Stable version)

mBiometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)
mBiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_WEAK)

Version 1.2.0-alpha04

mBiometricManager = BiometricManager.from(context)
mBiometricManager.canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_WEAK)

Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Update: Moved the same build to production, its working fine on production.